# How to get a representative sample from a large data frame given a factor

Tags: r, sampling

If one column is a factor, but each subset of the data frame has a different size -- maybe a subset has thousands of rows, while another has tens or hundreds of thousands of rows -- sampling done with `df[sample(nrow(df, n),]` might not have enough rows for a specific subset.

The sampled data frame will be turned into a jitter plot in ggplot2, and I would like each facet to have about the same sample size.

Comment: not sure if this belongs to CV or stackoverflow. Anyway, you can try the `createFolds` function (and variants, see helpfile) in the `caret` package.

Comment: This is called **stratified sampling**

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you're looking for the function `by`. The -`ply` functions from `package:plyr` will do a similar job. They're more powerful and flexible but a little trickier to use and typically not needed if you're already very comfortable with the base -`apply` functions.

There's one wrinkle. Running something like `by(iris,iris$Species,function(d) sample(nrow(d)))`, or its `plyr` equivalent, `dlply(iris,.(Species),function(d) sample(nrow(d)))`, will give you a sample from each sub-data-frame by Species... but it will be indexed with respect to that sub-data-frame and not the whole thing. This shouldn't be a problem *if* you design your data structure properly. Keep that in mind and write your plotting script accordingly. I would probably create something like a list of data frames that I can conveniently iterate over to plot each facet, but nobody ever accused me of being a good programmer.

Comment: So, far, I broke the logic in 2 parts: 

* `step1 <- dlply(iris,.(Species),function(d) { d[sample(nrow(d), 30),] }` -- to sample each factor
* `step2 <- ldply(step1, data.frame)` -- to recombine into 1 data frame

Answer (score 0):

Using @ssdecontrol's answer as a starting point, I came up with:

```
ddply(iris, .(Species), function(d) { d[sample(nrow(d), pmin(nrow(d), 2000)),] })
```

It takes the data frame apart by the `Species` factor, takes a sample of each subset, and puts it back together into a data frame.

I used `pmin(nrow(d), 2000)` to avoid the `cannot take a sample larger than the population` message.

In this case, `iris` is not the best example, it only contains 150 rows with only 50 rows per species — but the same logic was used against my original 1.6M rows data frame, which had one subset with fewer than 2000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

To perform a **stratified sample** where all factors are represented, you can use **group_by** and **sample_n** from the **dplyr** package:

```
set.seed(0) 
strat_iris <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  sample_n(5)
```

In this example, you get a 15-row dataset sample with 5 rows of each factor.